# Lower case in where clause

Tags: mysql, function, laravel-5

In my Laravel 5, I have this MySQL query

```
Menu::where('slug', '=', $slug)->count();
```

I'm trying to change `slug` in the DB to lowercase to match the sting in `$slug`.

I changed the query above to this,

```
Menu::where('LOWER(`slug`)', '=', $slug)->count();
```

and got this error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'LOWER(`slug`)' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: What database management system are you using? MySQL?

Comment: @jknotek yes mysql

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but note that the equality operator in MySQL is not case sensitive by default, so you may not even need the `LOWER` function.

Comment: @jknotek it is true that in many cases string equality comparisons are not case-sensitive, but to be precise, this is not related the equality operator.  The [collations of the comparison operands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) determine the rules for equality (as well as ordering).

Comment: @elife note you need to try to avoid using the general pattern of `FUNCTION(column)` in `WHERE` whenever possible, because this typically forces a full scan of all rows in the table.  An index on `slug` can't be effectively used if the query contains an expression like `LOWER(slug)`.  If by chance the slug is actually all-caps, you should instead convert `$slug` to upper instead.  It's logically equivalent but much faster with a large data set.  (Assuming a case conversion is even needed, as noted above.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use an expression that isn't a column name, you should use `DB::raw`:

```
Menu::where(DB::raw('LOWER(`slug`)'), $slug)->count();
```